# What frequency is this remote using?

Tags: identification, remote-control, 433mhz

I have a garage remote control I'm trying to duplicate, but the 433Mhz cloner I bought isn't responding to it.
Can anyone please confirm my remote is using 433Mhz frequency based on this circuit board image ? If not what frequency is it using ?

[image]

Comment: Can't follow the link.

Comment: Strange. Here's a link on imgur [Remote board](http://imgur.com/yA2gG0Y)

Comment: The image opens for me. The oscillator visible from the photo clearly shows 13.560MHz, I suppose it's possible they're doing a frequency multiplier to 433MHz, that is a pretty large multiplier though (~34). Hard to say without a schematic.

Comment: Make and model of the door opener or controller might help someone identify it...

Comment: Thanks for your help. Sadly, I have no way of knowing the make and model, nothing is written on the remote itself.

Comment: 13.56 MHz is a standard RFID frequency.

Comment: Yep, RFID based on the large loop antenna and the 13.56MHz. This is like a key fob right?

Comment: Many modern garage door openers now use an intelligent signalling scheme that is resistant to simple cloning....

Comment: If you posted what's written on the chips it would be more helpful. In your photo that is rather illegible. Actually you can probably google the ICs yourself...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably 433.92 MHz because that precise frequency is exactly 32 times higher than the 13.56 MHz xtal on the fob: -

[image]

433.92MHz is the centre frequency of the only ISM band that appears to reasonably be divided by 13.56 MHz. Maybe you need to give details on the cloner you have.

Comment: Thanks Andy for posting the image. The cloner is a cheap one from [ebay](http://www.ebay.fr/itm/331626571762?euid=f62eb4e9bb7f4deb9dd94cf51a66c4e1&cp=1)

Comment: but 13.56Mhz is right at the center of an ISM band?

Comment: @nils I discounted that one but, on closer inspection of the PCB there is a spiral antenna that could easily be resonant at that frequency. I think if the Op should tell us the max range normally achievable and this might give a clue.

Comment: Indeed, there is a spiral antenna on the inside of the remote (that I didn't think of photographing), the tip of which touches the ISM band when the remote is assembled. The max range is about 60 feet.

Comment: If you can get 60 feet and the antenna is connected via the spiral inductor then it's more likely to be 13.56 MHz. If the spiral was the antenna then you'd be lucky to get 6 feet and, given the likely inductance of the spiral, it won't work at 433 MHz.

Comment: What are the part numbers of the two 8 pin ICs? Can you show us a photo of the back side of the PCB?